# How to get current retry count while executing using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy

Tags: c#, exception, azure-sql-database, retry-logic

I'm currently using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy to implement retry login in my database transactions.

Here is the custom strategy which is inherited from SqlAzureExecutionStrategy :

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DbExecutionStrategy : SqlAzureExecutionStrategy
{
    private const int retryCount = 2;
    private static readonly TimeSpan maxDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    public DbExecutionStrategy ()
        : base(retryCount, maxDelay)
    {
    }

    public DbExecutionStrategy (int maxRetryCount, TimeSpan maxDelay)
        : base(maxRetryCount, maxDelay)
    {
    }

    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
    {
        if(exception.InnerException != null && exception.InnerException is SqlException)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm using this custom strategy like :

```
var executionStrategy = new DbExecutionStrategy();
executionStrategy.Execute(() => { some business logic here });
```

1. I want to print the current retry count inside the Execute method. Is it even possible?
   This is for the logging purpose. To see which retry yielded best results etc. Please feel free to suggest best retry count and maxDelay before the next retry.
2. In ShouldRetryOn method, what is the best way to define what are the exceptions you want to retry on? I'm hoping it is switch wth exceptions as cases and retrun true in each case.